# Find the kernel of T, basis for the kernel of T and the dimension of the kernel of T where $T:M_{2x2} \rightarrow M_{2x2}$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Let $T:M_{2x2} \rightarrow M_{2x2}$ be a transformation defined by $T(A)=A+A^T$ and let $A= \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\\end{bmatrix}$

Find the kernel of T, and basis for the kernel of T and the dimension of the kernel of T.

My attempt:
Set $T(A)=A+A^T=0= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\\end{bmatrix}+  \begin{bmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d \\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2a & b+c \\
b+c & 2d \\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}$
so, $a=d=0$ and $c=-b$
So the kernal of $T = \{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b \\
-b & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}: b\in\Bbb R\}$

Is that correct?

So the part I'm more confused on is is finding the basis of the kernel of T. 
Do I just set
$A= \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\\end{bmatrix}=0$ to get that the basis of the kernel is just $\{ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}\}$? or would the basis be $\{\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0  \\\end{bmatrix}\}$

The dimension of the kernel is just how many vectors there are right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

Following your result, $$\text{ker}T=\text{span}\{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}\}$$

So a basis to $\text{ker}T$ would be:

$$\{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}\}$$

As we get a basis with one matrix in it (note our space is of matrices and not vectors):

$$\text{dim}\text{Ker}T=1$$